Multiple questions regarding microphone/aux circuit
Shows a circuit that adds an aux input and a microphone input to output to speakers:

I have multiple questions regarding this circuit.
I have this circuit on a printed PCB but I am having several issues. The output of the circuit has heavy noise when the aux cable is connected, and the microphone does not work.
For reference, in this circuit each one of the 3 pin headers is a 20k ohm potentiometer.
I think I have spotted some errors in the circuit design already and I have listed them out below. I am wondering if the things I have spotted are correct and if there is any more that I have not spotted already.

I have the input of the microphone pulled up to 9 volts. I also have it being pulled up to 4.5 volts. This is a problem because the 9 volts is higher and the input to the opamp U1B is 9V volts and not 4.5.

The aux inputs are not pulled up to 4.5 volts for the input to the circuit. This means the summing amplifier inputs for aux left and aux right will be clipped on the bottom due to them going below 0 volts.

I do not have enough capacitance in this circuit overall. I replaced C1 from the op amp power input with a 1 mF capacitor.

I am wondering if the diodes will be clipping the output of the summing amplifier.

Any other things I am missing?


EDIT:

The board layout is shown above. It is a little messy as this is my first PCB design.
The microphone I am using is a Cylewet CYT1013 of which these are the most relevant statistics.

Frequency range: 50Hz - 20KHz
Current consumption: maximum 500uA
Standard operation voltage: 3V
Operation voltage range:1.5-10V

The audio jack is a SJ1-3525N stereo audio jack, which is rated for 12 volts 1 ampere.
The speakers are 3 W 8 ohm stereo speakers.

U2, U5 and U6 also need a 100nF decoupling capacitor.


Not a problem.  The job of coupling capacitor C6 is to assure that the bias point for the mic and the bias point for the opamp circuit are completely independent.  The value of R2 seems a little low to me.  This resistor is the load on the mic cartridge output.  Consider increasing it to 22K or even 47 K.  The mic output voltage will increase, but so will the circuit noise.  Life is choice.

Half right.  C3 (?), C17, and C22 are coupling capacitors, so the DC operating points on both sides of them can be different.  However, U1A pin 3, the non-inverting input, must be biased at VCCO2.  This sets the DC value of the opamp output midway between its rails.

ALL audio power amp ICs are very touchy about power supply decoupling.  Place a 0.1 uF ceramic cap from pin 6 to pin 4 as close as possible to the IC pins with the shortest possible leads.  Next, add an electrolytic cap in the 47 uF to 100 uF range, in parallel and again close-in.

Maybe; depends on the signal levels.

Other:


J1 pins 10 and 11 can be connected to GND.  This should prevent noise incursion when the AUX jack is not used.
Consider increasing R3 or C4.  As shown, they form a 160 Hz high-pass filter.
The output of U1B car drive the summing amp without C5 (?) and R6.
There is no apparent reason for having the LM741 in the circuit.  The rail-splitting function can be done with U1C or D if available.
Both the 741 and the 324 are relatively noisy ICs.  Also, the 324 has high crossover distortion.  Consider an alternative parts, such as something in the Texas Instruments TL07x or TL08x lines.


The pull-up to 9V should be ok, as it is blocked from the 4.5V by C6, hence ideally only AC flows through C6 after it has been charged to 4.5V(9V-4.5V). I don't see the microphone part number. I would need it to know whether the pull-up is correct or not.

That is not the case, the aux inputs are most likely 0-1V audio signal, but it is not guaranteed as I do not know what are you feeding to the jack connector.

A bigger decoupling capacitor will help with the power rail stability, but i don't think that is your biggest problem. If you want to change some capacitors, I would change the ones in the signal path to allow for lower frequencies. Also you should use low ESR capacitors in the signal path. In addition as @Tyassin already mentioned, you need decoupling capacitors close to each opamp.

Yes they will. They will clamp the output to +-0.7V.

I would not recommend this circuit, although you can make it work somehow by tweaking the parameters, it will never maintain audio quality. Also the noise pickup and audio quality is highly dependent on the actual layout. Could you provide it?


So overall, it is nice to see a fellow audiophile, but in order to help you I would need more information(microphone specs, layout, jack input specs,...).
Hope this helps at least a bit.
Take care!

I agree this is one of the most interesting projects I have worked on. As much as it is frustrating to get to work I couldn't help but have a beaming smile the first time I plugged in the aux and noise came out of the speakers. I have updated the original post with some additional information. I also included the speakers I got as well.

I see. The layout doesn't look that bad for a first PCB, although here are some basic misunderstandings. First of all, decoupling needs to be place as close to the ICs as possible, imagine the current flowing only from the decoupling capacitor into the IC V+ and then returning from the V- pin back to the capacitor and try to minimize the loop. Another problem might be, that you are using THT components in way too dense design. Your groun poor on bottom side is then effectively cut by the leads. The current then has to take a longer path.

Don't take me wrong as i like your board and I've seen much worse first designs :). I would recommend you to read a bit about PCB design basics, there's load of stuff on the internet. If you want to read somthing about the power amplifier stages you can try Bob Cordells "Designing Audio Power Amplifiers", althoug it might be pretty overwhelming for a begginer. Keep up the good work!


You only have the MIC pulled up to 9V. The opamp input is pulled to 4.5V. That's why the capacitor is there, to block DC and pass AC.

No they are not pulled to 4.5V but they don't need to be - the DC is blocked by capacitors. The only issue is, the bias should come from the op-amp via negative feedback. Because opamp positive input is grounded, it's the op-amp that's biased incorrectly. As a side note, C5 and R6 are useless because you have C17 and R31.

A 1000 uF capacitor would be quite useless. Of course it depends on if you intend to power this from a 9V block battery and drive 4 ohm speakers at full power, because the battery really can't do that anyway, and the capacitor would just delay the inevitable.

Yes, if the amplitude is high enough, the diodes will clip - that's why they are there. Low enough amplitude and they don't clip. It's more like if they should be somewhere else in the design instead.

Maybe. It depends what this thing is supposed to do, what kind of signals it gets in and what kind of signals it must send out. The potentiometer values and their connections are undetermined. With 9V supply the chip can output about 8Vpp into no load or less than 4Vpp into 4 ohms. As the chip has a gain of 20, you get 8Vpp with only 0.4Vpp input. and 0.8Vpp is what the chip allows if it had more supply. The speaker output caps are 470nF, it is likely an error as 470uF would sound more correct for driving speakers. Based on drawing, the left and right channels look like swapped, but it's a mono summer so it does not matter.




Why is C2 useless? @Justme.


But isn't C2 the decoupling cap on U1?

@Tyassin Thanks, the yellow box covered the designator and I mean C5 and C17. I will edit the post.
